# Really clear screen when using minicom

Tags: 20.04, minicom

I'm using `minicom -w -D /dev/ttyUSB0` on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS to communicate through a USB to serial converter with an embedded Linux. I want to clear the screen in the same manner as `reset` does when using `ssh` or when just plain typing in a new terminal. That is: when I scroll up after clearing, I don't want old output to show up again (which is what `clear` would do). While in `minicom`, the behavior of `reset` is the same as `clear`, which is not what I want.

How do I clear the screen "properly" while in `minicom`?
Bonus points if it works while a command is running.

These I have tried:

- Exiting minicom with `Ctrl+A, Z, X`, then `reset`, then entering `minicom` again: Works, but it's annoying to have to do this.
- `Ctrl+A, Z, C` (labeled as "Clear Screen"): Has the same behavior as `clear`
- `Ctrl+L`: Has the same behavior as `clear`
- `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+C`: Doesn't work while inside `minicom`
- `tput reset`: `tput` does not exist on the target system.
- `clear && printf '\e[3J'`: Has the same behavior as `clear`
- `clear && clear`: Has the same behavior as `clear`
- `stty sane`: Has no visible effect at all
- `printf "\033c"`: Positions the caret at the top left, but doesn't clear the screen, also same behavior as `clear`
- `setterm -reset`: `setterm` does not exist on the target system.
- `Ctrl+Shift+K`: Has no visible effect at all

Comment: I'd suggest applying security fixes & other upgrades to your system asap if it's used online; a [correctly upgraded 20.04 system will report much later](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2023/03/23/ubuntu-20-04-6-lts-released/) but your provided details imply you've not applied security fixes since before late [February 2022}(https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) as release dates in my links apply to ISOs for new installs, but installed systems upgraded before those dates.  Are you using Ubuntu 20.04? as the detail you applied does match Ubuntu based but non-Ubuntu systems

Comment: @guiverc Does that fix my problem?

Comment: How would I know; all I know from your details is you're either not using a Ubuntu system (*but a Ubuntu-based system built on an outdated Ubuntu product*) or have a non-Ubuntu system that hasn't been updated & is behind on loads of fixes & thus can act very different to a patched & secure Ubuntu system. I can't know what you've left *unpatched*, except leaving fixes un-applied can cause the version number to show as *outdated* as you mentioned.  I'll suggest keeping your system off-line though.